# Server instance is not configured. Class Not Found: VersionLoggerListener

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to set up tomcat 7.0.57 to run a web application, in Eclipse Luna. I've added the webapp to the server, and tried to publish the serve but I get this error:

```
Dec 05, 2014 10:07:13 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

Dec 05, 2014 10:07:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (21, 76) : org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
Dec 05, 2014 10:07:13 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:679)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Dec 05, 2014 10:07:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (21, 76) : org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
Dec 05, 2014 10:07:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Clearly something is wrong with the `VersionLoggerListener` because it can't find it. All my server.xml (accessed via my workspace folder) contains on line 21 is this:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
```

Which seems pretty innocent. Googling doesn't seem to tell me this is missing in other peoples tomcat packages.

Checking my 'installation' of tomcat, it looks like this line is missing from the equivalent server.xml

Should they be the same? Which should I point to Workspace version, or installation version?

I don't know what's up though, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6559952/1075247/) it implied that their equivalent `ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener` was recently added and it's some kind of version conflict, which I don't think is the case here (?) as both are version 7 of tomcat.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16933462/1075247) it looks like a jar is missing, but I don't know how that would happen as I'm sure `VersionLoggerListener` is a core class to catalina and should be there as part of the installation.

So what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two different version of Tomcat going. I deleted the server (using the server view) and then re-added it pointing to the installation.

Comment: delete all tmp folders in 
`.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core`
tomcat will create the these folders when published from server view 
So from new server , these folders are overwritten and contains files from both tomcats ,

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue while switching Tomcat7 to Tomcat6.

Because the conf folder under `CATALINA_BASE` folder, you were using was from different tomcat version from current version.

In Tomcat 7, you will find `VersionLoggerListener` in `server.xml`

To start tomcat, just change the folder pointing to new location of `CATALINA_BASE` with `conf` folder OR DELETE the `conf` folder and replace it with your current tomcat conf.

For Eclipse, server Folder:`.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf`

Answer (score 1):

I was using Tomcat 7, and then I installed Tomcat 6 in a different folder and I tried runing both Tomcat versions in separate workstations in eclipse.

Somehow Tomcat 7 did not state the same error in eclipse console.

I deleted Tomcat 7 from Eclipse and reset the Tomcat 7 server.

This workaround resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error also happens if you copy some files between tomcat installations.

For example if files from the /lib folder of 7.0.57 are copied to 7.0.99, take care to reinstall the libraries according to the tomcat version.